# Request role for use command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to use this simple code for a member with request role only ( if u dont have request role bot dont send any msg ) and a cmd for store role request

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("pong");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

how can u do that
i try to use some code like message.member.roles but in not work ;.;
thank for help me
or if u have free time can u pin your discord i want to ask smth like that ( first time codeing but this is so interesting )

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your attempt using `message.member.roles`

Comment: I trying to use that but cant, do u have any idea about my problem

Comment: You're in the right direction when using that. If you show how you tried using that we can see where your mistake is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much to go forward with your question but the best guess I have is that you want to limit your command to be used only by specific users with specific role.

This is how you would achieve this:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    if(msg.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === 'YOUR-ROLE-ID-HERE')){
        //STUFF HAPPENS IF THE ROLE IS FOUND
        msg.reply(`PONG`)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi thank for help me, the ‘your id here’ can i make a cmd can store info about user have that role, or when i used add @user ‘request role’ bot can be used by that user

Comment: It like “DJ” role if u have that role u can manage music, i want that for my bot ;.;